# Is it possible to update application build level (version) using wsadmin

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, wsadmin

Is it possible to update the build level (version) for a deployed application in Websphere 8.5 using wsadmin AdminApp?

I am aware that its an 'uneditable' field in admin console, and that the build level is read from the implementation-version property in manifest.mf file of the application.  However, I am curious to know if its possible to update it via wsadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that field is read-only according to [this IBM KnowledgeCenter topic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/rxml_taskoptions.html) on the wsadmin AdminApp object.

> buildVersion
>
> The buildVersion option displays the build version of an application EAR file. You cannot modify this option because it is read-only. This option returns the build version information for an application EAR if you have specified the build version in the MANIFEST.MF application EAR file.